# Devise Omniauth undefined method omniauth_authorize_path

Tags: devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've noticed that when logging to Devise I have started to receive these error message.

I'm using Devise 2.2.4 with Omniauth 1.1.4 and Omniauth-Facebook 1.4.1

Does anybody know what is the cause of this error?

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0xb85e534>:0xb904e5c>):
21: <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
22:   <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
23:     <% logger.info "hey #{provider} , dolphin and #{resource_name}" %>
24:     <%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
25:   <% end -%>
26: <% end -%>

  app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_devise_shared__links_erb___1039642231_94147460'
  app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb:22:in `each'
  app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb:22:in `_app_views_devise_shared__links_erb___1039642231_94147460'
  app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb__883448937_92868060'
```

Answer (score 21):

One possible mistake is that omniauth configuration is set at the wrong place.

I encountered this error because I set my facebook accounts in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`, as instructed by the omniauth readme.

However we need to set it through devise, i.e. `config/initializers/devise.rb` at the omniauth section.

Answer (score 11):

I started getting this error today (Jul 27, 2016) when I upgraded to Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 4.2.7. The solution that worked for me was to change all instances of `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter)` to `user_twitter_omniauth_authorize_path`.

Comment: Same here, appears to be a change in devise 4.x. Downgrading devise to 3.5.6 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider)
```

I'm assuming you have a User class and in your routes file you have

```
devise_for :users
```

Comment: This happens at build-in /users/sign_in view.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like that

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", public_send("user_#{provider.to_s}_omniauth_authorize_path") %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

This makes it usable for multiple providers but it assumes you are using

```
devise_for :users
```

But going even further you could also add

```
resource_class.name.downcase
```

to cover not only user

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
     <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", public_send("#{resource_class.name.downcase}_#{provider.to_s}_omniauth_authorize_path") %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

If devise_for is users and provider is facebook, then it will make path:

> user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path

if devise_for is admins and provider twitter, then it will make path:

> admin_twitter_omniauth_authorize_path

Answer (score 3):

If you initialize your devise providers in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` You should include `Devise::OmniAuth::UrlHelpers` in your `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` or `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Devise changed the url helper to be `omniauth_authorize_path(<scope>, <provider>)`

See here:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FOmniAuth%2FUrlHelpers%3Aomniauth_authorize_path

Answer (score 1):

In your app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb :

change

`omniauth_authorize_path`

to

`user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider)`